# Why does the creation of an index take a long time?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008.

i am creating an NON CLUSTERED index on a table in my database.

What I see while creating that index is that the query is taking a lot of time; in my case now 8-9 mins is done but still create index query is running.

Can somebody help me to get why it is so ?

Comment: The time required to create an index is proportional to the number of rows you have. If you have a ton of rows, it will take a while.

Comment: @marc_s i Have primary key on it so definitelly there will be a clustered Index created automatically.

Comment: Without a ball park figure of how many rows are in your database, if this is a single column or composite key and the general spec and load on your server this would be very hard to answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would bet there's nothing special causing it to be slow outside of the ordinary considerations.  Obviously the number of rows in the database is going to be a primary factor, then the processor speed and amount of memory on your computer.  Also, many people do not realize how much the hard disk speed affects sql operations.  Depending on how you use sql, you could easily increase speed quite noticeably by just getting a faster hard drive.